# Bold code in a question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, source-code

Frequently when I ask a question I have to include quite a bit of code for reference purposes.

It would be nice to be able to bold the important lines in the code.

For example this code:

```html
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
            <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Is not way long, but the important part (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889108/wpf-datatrigger-setting-listboxitem-isselected)) is the second to last line.  However, if I try to bold it, it ends up looking like this:

```html
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
            <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    **<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>**
</DataTrigger>
```

Not what I was going for.  It would be nice to be able to draw attention to specific lines of code when needed.

(One suggestion of a different color background sounds nice too (ie a yellow background to draw the eye to the relevant code.)

If there is some other way to bold in code please let me know.

Comment: I'm almost certain I've seen this suggestion before. I still like it.

Comment: I like this idea but the only problem I see with it is people writing C/C++ like this: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Now everything after that will be bold.

Comment: Maybe some special in code bold syntax?  Something sufficiently weird as to not clash with code?

Comment: What could possibly be weird enough as to not clash with at least one language out there?

Comment: Yeah, Perl could clash with pretty much anything from what I've seen.

Comment: If you want to avoid the theoretical possibility of clashing, you need an escape mechanism.  Begins to sound complex, unlike tvanfosson's suggestion...

Comment: +1, I like this suggestion.

Comment: Started a bounty in hopes that this can actually be done.

Comment: Any chance of a comment from the Site owners on this?  It would be nice to know if it has been seen, considered or (sigh) rejected.

Comment: Hmmmm, just declined.  No reason?  Too hard?  Not seen as important?  Any comment at all?

Comment: I would like to see this feature for answers too, to emphasize the change I made to questioner's original code to make it work.

Comment: Wait, when did we vote on this? I see its marked as declined. Where/how is voting on new features done?

Comment: @Nick - there is no voting.  Features for SO are not run in a democratic or republic sense.  We submit them and they decide if they are good or not.  (Though if this got voted up a lot they may re-look at it.)  Jeff shot this one down without even a reason why...  (It kind of irked me at the time.)

Comment: For the record, you *can* do it already if you mark your code with `<pre><code>` instead of four spaces. You're forfeiting the automatic escape of HTML/XML characters though.

Comment: If the code for in code bold needs to be complicated to avoid clashes with other languages just make the bold button context sensitive, it can then put in whatever madness is required

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Please can you ping someone and get the status of these fixes?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I see a few options:

1. Simply add a comment in the appropriate language syntax to draw attention to the important line of code.
2. However, It might be better to have **automatic line numbering for code blocks**, so then you can just say "*see here on line X...*".

If you are including so much code that it is not clear which are the "important" parts, generally you are including too much code. Try to boil it down to the smallest working example possible.

Comment: This * 100.  Line numbering would make it soooo much easier to refer to different sections of code, and could make answers shorter as they wouldn't need to include the whole code if only a few line changes are needed.

Comment: Line numbering is a bad idea because it makes it difficult to copy and paste the code so that it can be compiled outside of the browser. If you need to hilight a line, simply use a comment in the language if the code. For example: int x = 4 / 0; // ERROR HERE!

Comment: @Neil - I agree.  I often cut from questions into a file to test -- having to edit a question just to get at the code in a usable form seems wrong.

Comment: +1 for all the goto answers people will raise

Comment: It should be possible to separate the line numbers from the code through the proper use of HTML/CSS... I am several years out of date now but shouldn't a separate table cell or div be sufficient here?

Comment: @Æther: There are even some examples out there. Google does it: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-vb.js

Comment: When changing the rendering, then existing code blocks might suddenly look funny though... Not all pre-formatted text is actually code on these sites.

Comment: @nb69307, Gosh, this is not the '90s. It's not difficult to copy and paste the code with proper HTML.

Answer (score 72):

You could always try to create the HTML by hand:

```html
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
            <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

```html
<pre><code>&lt;DataTrigger Value="True"&gt;
    &lt;DataTrigger.Binding&gt;
        &lt;MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}"&gt;
            &lt;Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/&gt;
            &lt;Binding Path="Id"/&gt;
        &lt;/MultiBinding&gt;
    &lt;/DataTrigger.Binding&gt;
    &lt;Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/&gt;
    <b>&lt;Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/&gt;</b>
&lt;/DataTrigger&gt;
</code></pre>
```

I would like to point out that you will have to replace `<` with `&lt;`, and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: interesting.  i didn't know `<pre><code>` would trigger the syntax highlighting, thx!

Comment: yeah, this is about the only real solution

Comment: I'm waiting for the greasemonkey solution for this.

Comment: @Jeff: You could always extend the markdown syntax.

Comment: This kinda proves that emboldening code is futile since the bold line barely stands out at all (for me, anyway).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, That depends on the font.

Comment: Just want to clarify that you DO NOT have to replace both brackets `<` and `>` in your HTML block for it to display properly.

You can just replace the first bracket `<` and it'll do the job.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/gb5ujy14/1/

Comment: How do you specify a language to enable highlighting in `<pre><code>`?

Comment: It is like this: `<pre><code class="language-bash">`.

Answer (score 36):

I've done this on occasion, though I can't find the answers in which I've done it.

`this is bold code and this isn't`

And this is how I did it:

```
<code>this is **bold code** and this isn't</code>
```

or also:

`this is bold code and this isn't`

And this is the source:

```
<code>this is <b>bold code</b> and this isn't</code>
```

Comment: This is the easiest!

Comment: this also works on github, where i needed it.

Comment: This is single-line only

Comment: @Pacerier: you can wrap this all in `<p>...</p>` and make it multiline

Comment: @Pacerier Adding a `>` to make it a quote seems to work...for making it multi-line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UY2.png. Of course, non of this is really ideal.

Answer (score 28):

Not pretty, just a workaround.

Ascii art is your friend.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
            <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>     <-----+
</DataTrigger>                                              |
                                                            |
                                                            |
             yo, this line here! ----------------------------
```

Comment: Normally what I do is take a screenshot of the code and draw free-hand circles around the problem area.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles!  i think ascii art is probably faster tho...

Comment: Uhh, unless the very same code is available as text as well, I dislike screenshots of code, as then others might need to type the code in their answers. (Likewise for screenshots of error messages. And, it's not very SEO-friendly.)

Comment: @Dexter, Screenshots make it invisible to Google. Not good. Screenshot + text is a clear violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 25):

Usually I will tag a comment on the line I'm trying to highlight.  Comments have different syntax highlighting than normal code.  Perhaps the highlighting of comments could be made bold to make it more noticeable or the bold highlighting only apply in a commented section?

```
  var foo = new Bar();  // here is the problem...
```

Comment: or use whitespace + comments above & below the problem line to further distinguish it...

Comment: True this can work.  But bold draws attention much easier.  Especially when your code already has other comments in it.

Comment: if you put your code up as whitespace... it's be hard to follow ;)

Comment: @warren, indeed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29 ;-)

Comment: I think comments are the way to go, but what about a way to make *specific* comments stand out, per [my answer](#32931)?

Comment: I think that just turning on mark up in comment sections would be sufficient, if possible.  I don't know that we need to introduce new mark up elements.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you are saying ALL comments should be highlighted (I disagree) or if **bold** escape codes should be enabled inside comments (I agree)

Comment: I would experiment with both, but simply changing the style of the comments so that that aren't "grayed out" may be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

That sounds like a good idea. Here's how I would implement it:

### Unformatted markdown

```
Here's my example code:

    var fruit = "Apple"
 -> if isRipe(fruit) do
        eat(fruit)
    end
```

### Rendered post

Lines having that arrow should automatically be highlighted with a differently coloured background. Maybe one could add a reference number for each highlighted line.

> Here's my example code:
>
> ```
>  var fruit = "Apple"
>  if isRipe(fruit) do                                                       [1]
>      eat(fruit)
>  end
> ```

Comment: Pre doesn't apply code highlighting, which is not great.  But the idea that we ought to have additional markup which highlights a line with a yellow background is awesome.

Comment: I cannot recall mentioning <pre>…

Comment: Ah, you have the `<code>` inside the `<pre>` - that's not too bad.

Comment: I was ok with this until I started thinking about how I actually use code in a question.  If I want to test something I'll cut/paste from the question.  Now -- except for inconsistent line breaks -- it works pretty much as advertised.  With comments it still works as long as the comment is in the language of the code.  With this I'll have to edit it up to get it to work.  Not enough of an improvement over comments or a solution highlighting comments to make it worth the drop off in functionality.

Comment: @tvanfosson: That's a thought worth considering. Have you seen how popular frameworks add line numbers to code? They use their own container which makes it possible to only copy the code. That's certainly something that would be possible for the line marker too. (One negative side of it is that this needs even more horizontal space.)

Comment: @Pollyanna: You seem to have misunderstood me. I'll try to clarify my post.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Why not just copy the rendered version of the code?  The bold will not require any special fixing if you copy from the rendered version will it?

Comment: I like the idea of differently colored background (ie yellow).  That would make it even clearer than bold.

Comment: The problem with -> is C++ uses it to access pointer properties.

Comment: @Macha: But not in the first 4 characters, which tell markdown that it's a code section.

Answer (score 4):

Some IDEs look for keywords within comments and treat them like bookmarks. Specifically, if you type `TODO: fix this bug` in a comment it is added as an item in the "table of contents" pop up menu.

What if a special keyword or syntax *within a comment* triggered the highlighting?  For example:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
            <Binding Path="Id"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/> <!-- HELP: here is the problem -->
</DataTrigger>
```

`HELP:` seems like a reasonable keyword that won't generate too many false positives. Either the background of the line could be colored, or (this may be simpler to implement) that particular comment can receive louder formatting (since the default comment formatting is light gray text).

Comment: And this annotative method could be used by any editor or IDE for the same effect, making it an ad-hoc standard of sorts. Advantages over all the other methods discussed here: 1. Copy-paste safe 2. Rendered text identical to markdown 3. No new MD syntax or tags 4. Comment ensures safe fencing in all languages 5. Safe for renderers who don't adopt it.

Answer (score 3):

After looking through all conservations, I still think that bolding in code is handy, especially for those who doesn't have much time. Yeah, there's many other ways to draw attention, but bolding just seems easier for starter.

Comment: If users "don't have much time" then they don't have enough time to thin and  write a good question and review the answers

Comment: @Mark: it's certainly not true.

Comment: According to your saying, if I don't have much time, I won't eat/sleep/work... as well

Answer (score 3):

In addition, sometimes it's useful to be able to have formatting inside code blocks: for instance, to represent some "computer-genic" hierarchical structure (e.g. filesystem) with nested lists. *Or should code blocks be used for that at all?* Triple backticks are used for block code with ignored formatting. Double backticks are **redundantly used same as single ones** (except with some added escaping functionality). My suggestion is to use double backticks for **block code with allowed formatting**. (By the way, it resembles strict equality check `===` vs loose one `==` in some programming languages :)

Usage examples (notice the double backticks):

This...:

```
``
- c:
    - documents and settings
        - admin
        - all users
        - default user
        - *username*
            - application data
            - local settings
                - temp
    - program files
        - Microsoft Office
        - Windows Media Player
    - Windows
        - fonts
        - system32
``
```

...should generate this:

```
c:documents and settingsadminall usersdefault userusernameapplication datalocal settingstempprogram filesMicrosoft OfficeWindows Media PlayerWindowsfontssystem32
```

and this...:

```
``
create [temp|temporary] table [if not exists] *table-name* (
    *column-name* [*type-name*]
)
``
```

...should generate this:

```
create [temp|temporary] table [if not exists] table-name (
    column-name [type-name]
)
```

and since markdown isn't markup, markup shouldn't be rendered, but stay literal, as written:

```
``
<book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    **<price>44.95<price> <!-- error: wrong closing tag -->**
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
``
```

the above generates this (markup is untouched):

```
<book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95<price> <!-- error: wrong closing tag -->
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
```

If you need markup formatting flexibility (e.g. colored highlights), you can wrap your code in `<pre><code>` and style as you wish (until markdown introduces similar styling possibilities).

Answer (score 2):

The OP picked XAML to ask the question, when dealing with XML-based languages it would be hard using `pre`/`code`, but for the reference, if you're dealing with C# for example or any other language not involving a lot of less-than/greater-than signs, this should be really easy to achieve.

This:

```
public void Greet()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

Would be rendered from the following input:

```
<pre>
public void Greet()
{
    Console.WriteLine(<b>"Hello world!"</b>);
}
</pre>
```