# Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, blockquote

It would be nice to be able to put emphasis on specific bits of a fragment or of a quote (bold can help for a quote but I find that it makes things less readable sometimes).

What do you think?

**Update:** On http://www.pastebin.com/, you can *highlight particular lines by prefixing each line with `@@`*.

#### See also:

> - [Bold code in a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question)

Comment: Really nice idea. I think it may tempt n00bs to abuse it when posting huge chunks of code ("Hey, I highlighted the relevant part!!!"), but that's easily dealt with.

Comment: @Jon As long as they format their code, I'd accept to deal with that :)

Comment: Very nice indeed, but please not with that unreadable color-combination :)

Answer (score 25):

I like the idea.

For highlighting a whole line, one could extend the markdown syntax and define that an asterisk before the four spaces required to highlight a code block highlights that line:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++)
     {  
*      print "$i lines!";  // this line gets highlighted
     }
```

this would work without having to work out a character or character sequence that turns on highlighting within a block.

Comment: First suggestion I've seen that would work. No opposed.

Comment: Not that i think its very important, but could we mark the first line that way too the way SOs markdown works?

Comment: @Georg no, but arguably the first line is easy to point out in the text body.

Answer (score 4):

What about just breaking up the code block?

---

You need to use the `print` function:

```
function foobar()
{
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++)
  {
```

```
    print "$i lines!";
```

```
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably leave out the explanatory text though. The break in the code block would be enough to notice. Writing the explanation that way is harder to read, especially in a larger block of code. You could still leave the explanatory native comment within the block though.

Comment: @Jeff: I like it. See my revised answer

Comment: I'd leave out the horizontal lines though.  You can get away with leaving those out.  I'll edit your answer if you don't mind just to show what I mean.  Rollback or improve if you wish.

Comment: @JeffMercado Even better, thanks! I couldn't easily figure out how to do that, which is why I was using the `<hr>`s

Comment: It's a work-around. The only thing it highlights is that you can't highlight a line in a code block

Answer (score 1):

Meh.

IMHO, if a code block is so large that a simple comment like this:

```
blah.blah.blah(arg, arg, arg);
class.class.method(arg, arg, arg + 1, weird_arg, blah);  // <-- something strange happens here
blah.blah.blah(arg, arg, arg);
```

...doesn't stand out on its own, then chances are the code block is including too much and the example should be pared down a bit.

Comment: Well, using comments is what I currently do but 1. you sometimes needs the whole context of a piece of code, 2. comments might not get spotted and 3. I find it limiting, especially when dealing with XML blocks. Not to mention that comments doesn't work with quotes.

Comment: @Ether I disagree. It is often necessary to post a full block of code to make a diagnosis, and being able to highlight the line the compiler/interpreter chokes at would be a good thing.

Comment: @Down: Pare it down: if you can't pare it down you're only guessing about where the trouble is in any case.

Comment: @dmckee I disagree, especially newbies who get a "error x on line 188" often need to show a whole block to make sense, but it would be great to know where line 188 is in all that, which is where the highlighting comes in. But +1 for teaching me a new english word.

Comment: @Down: Maybe it's the teacher in me, but I see that as an opportunity to teach the new programmers that vital debugging skill of isolating the offending code.

Comment: @dmckee: As long as SO is open to beginners there will always be people who can't identify the relevant parts properly. Even non-beginners may have that problem - e.g. plain COM programming carries so much visual noise that its hard to trim or reduce to a few central lines. gtk+ using C is also quite line-hungry.

Comment: It's not about the size of the block, it's about highlighting that part that matters.