# Line highlighting within code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote)

Would it be possible to add a "Highlight" function to code blocks?

For example, with

```
function foo ($fbar = false)
{
   if($bar)
   {
       echo 'Hello'
   }
}
```

the echo statement could be highlighted so that responders can see clearly where the error is being caused.

The reason I think this would be a good idea to implement is that the posted code may only be a snippet from their source and the line numbers that the compilers throw would be different than the line numbers within the snippet.

On http://pastebin.com, before it was taken over by new owners, you had the choice to place an `@` symbol at the head of a line to highlight the line.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Already suggested at [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote)

Comment: Hate it when that happens :(