# Code highlighting improvement suggestion

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote)

Sometimes I need to paste a large lump of code, as in context it is all relevant, but I would like people to perhaps start reading the code from a specific point, or to bring their attention to a specific part of the code first instead of them having to trawl linearlly through initially irrelevant stuff.

It would be good to have code highlighting I think.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My gut feeling is that if you need such a feature, then you already pasted too much code.

- Explain the problem in specific terms - what is failing and how.
- Paste only the code that is necessary (the one you would like to highlight).
- If necessary - or if people ask you for it, add a few lines of code that detail how the previous relevant code is initialized, how it is used, etc.

**EDIT**: If you feel that you have a question for which those guidelines fail, then feel free to post a link to it. I'd rather teach you how to phrase better questions.