# underlining with `<u>` does not work in `<pre>`

Tags: support, markdown, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Within the `<pre>`-environment the tag `<u>` has no visible effect (Firefox 7.0.1 but also earlier like 3.6.17). I would expect it to underline. I use `<b>` already to mean something else (user input - the `<kbd>` is not very readable for this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)... `<u>` is (thankfully) [not supported at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites#comment50759_24142), regardless of `<pre>`. Aside: the more you get carried away with the formatting, the less readable your post usually gets. Simpler is better.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: I need the extra formatting for explaining transscripts and program slices.

Comment: Don't use `<pre>` blocks when you want rich text formatting. Simple.

Comment: @The Establishment: How else should I format and annotate program text easily?

Comment: You aren't supposed to "format" program text. It isn't formatted in your editor, either. Use *words* to *describe* the problem. See, for example, these questions: [Bold code in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32705) [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54392) [Formatting the code block?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128951) [Code highlighting improvement suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68612) [Some way to put emphasis on code, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72852)

Comment: @The Establishment: I **do** format program slices.  That is, these are programs but annotated w.r.t. a specific semantics. [Here is a recent example of me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141181/772868). Please follow the link in the text to see what I mean.

Comment: @The Establishment: Thank you for the references. I went through all of them. The recommendations made are essentially: Quote less program text and the like. But please look at my examples: They are already very short right from the beginning!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the language under discussion there, so your code samples don't make any sense to me. But in general, I don't understand the purpose for underlining and bolding code. Just leave it out if it doesn't belong.

Comment: Also, even in standard HTML, that wouldn't work they way you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<u>` tags are stripped, they are not in the list of allowed HTML for Stack Overflow's Markdown.

See [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Yeah exactly...

Comment: So how do we underline things, then?

Comment: @endolith You don't. [We don't allow underlining on our sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-not-underline)

Comment: I̲ ̲g̲u̲e̲s̲s̲ ̲w̲e̲'̲l̲l̲ ̲h̲a̲v̲e̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲f̲i̲n̲d̲ ̲w̲o̲r̲k̲a̲r̲o̲u̲n̲d̲s̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲n̲?̲