# Would it be possible to note the close reason in the top line

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, closed-questions

I think it would be very helpful to see the close reason at once.
The most frequent reasons are

- off topic
- duplicate question
- migrated too

I often look at SQL questions in stackoverflow and there seems to be lots of duplicate questions and I would like to have a quick way to ignore the duplicates.

Comment: Duplicates have the words **Possible Duplicate**, in bold, automatically inserted as the very first line of the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Agree, when you look at the individual question, I refer to the lists like newest.

Comment: Are you referring to the title, similar to [Closed]?

Comment: Yes. 'Possible Duplicate' is there in the two lines of the text, but not the bold.

Comment: You could just ignore all closed questions, regardless of close reason...

Comment: would be nice to have a filter for that

Comment: `closed:0` is the filter

Comment: this one is closed as duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72852/some-way-to-put-emphasis-on-code-please-closed, but the list only shows: Some way to put emphasis on code, please [closed]
… Since the syntax highlighter knows from comments, you could recogn … as matching delimiters (using whatever comment syntax is active). …