# Different background color for intentionally bad or wrong code blocks

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes code is included in an answer in order to show what *not* to do. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552350/string-isnullorempty-check-for-space/2552389#2552389):

> ```
> String foo = null;
> String.IsNullOrEmpty( foo.Trim())
> ```
>
> ...Throws an exception as `foo` is
>   Null.

The correct code is usually listed later in the answer. In the interest of preventing careless visitors from quickly copying and pasting the code the author *didn't* want them to use, it would be nice if there was a way to mark bad or dangerous code so the background was a light red color instead of grey (for example).

As an example of how this could be automatically displayed, when the first line of a code block is a comment with a particular message, the code block's background would be changed, or perhaps a little warning triangle icon would be added.

Trigger possibilities:

```
// Bad code
/* Dangerous code */
# Incorrect code
```

Just an idea.

Comment: Related (and far more generic, and hence more useful in my opinion): [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote).

Answer (score 4):

If people are just blindly pasting code without thought or care they kind of deserve what they get, don't you think? It might sound harsh but I definitely don't want that coder writing stuff that I'm going to use or maintain.

A way to highlight code manually might be useful though.

Comment: I still think the suggestion would be useful, just not for the same reason.  If your first block of (bad) example code is clearly marked, it might stop people from downvoting without finishing reading your answer.