# Changed handles leading to confusion in comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name)

Have noticed occasionally a comment `@` someone's handle that isn't found anywhere on the page (using a browser's search functionality) - Example [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote#comment128114_54395), and subsequent comments supposedly directed towards @Down

I presume this is because OP's sometimes change handles, but the system doesn't change these elements in posts.

Any chance of making the system change all @oldhandles, to the new handle upon OP change?

Comment: I see no instance in that question where the @name is not on the page.