# Highlighting and notating part of a line in a code block

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

There is a need to highlight, or more precisely bring attention to, *part* of a line of code, that the current markdown does not support.

First let's establish if that statement is true.

Here are just some of hundreds of posts this year alone where the poster needed to highlight parts of a line and used just one type of work around:

Some answers by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) (246K ranked 31), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869411/running-same-jquery-function-on-many-elements-with-same-id/20869426#20869426):

```
$('.edit').each(...);
// ^---- ., not #, for class
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872082/what-is-the-equivalent-of-luas-ellipsis-in-javascript/20872132#20872132):

```
FuncCallHack(SomeFunction, [1, 2, 3]);
// Note this is an array --^-------^
```

And another by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) (171K ranked 61), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887721/how-to-create-timer-in-java/20887765#20887765):

```
Timer Timer = new Timer();
      ^---- capital T
timer.schedule();
^---lower case T
```

Note that these guys are amongst the top contributors in the community, and if they felt the need to bring attention to some particular code characters, it is reasonable to accept that there's a "need".

[Using data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/167666/post-count-since-start-of-2014-that-used-ascii-highlight), I found that since the start of this year, there have been 853 posts that used this type of work around, and T.J. Crowder does 2 per week. So, hopefully I've established reasonable support for the need. I certainly believe a decent code highlighting capability would be a big plus. With, or without a notation.

Now then, what to do about it? What are the requirements?
From a strictly behavioural perspective:

Whole-line highlighting is not a solution. While it may on occasion be enough, it alone is inadequate and may be considered an edge case of a solution.

A simple color reversal (like selected text) might be a good first implementation.

A superimposed felt-tip pen style underline for characters in the code would be great, so it might look like this.

[image: highlighted code without popup]

The optional notation could even be a rollover popup over the code, with the underline under the code fragment left as permanent highlighting, so with the popup active:

[image: highlighted code with popup]

Or leave the popup active all the time (implementation choice - whatever).

But, how much more clear is this type of rendering than the lame ascii art pointer?

If an clean markdown extension could be created to render like this, it would be awesome.

Just one idea might be (don't get too hung up on this rough proposition - we can figure out the details later if this idea gets support):

```
$('{!.!:dot, not #, for class}edit').each(...);
```

So, what do you think?

p.s. I'll put my hand up to help do the work to make this happen.

Comment: Yes! There have been several times when I've written "you see the second i on the first line,  that should be an x". This would make that far less clunky

Comment: Very much related, but without a specific rendering request: [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote). I don't see how encoding the hint in the code block itself won't mess up though. There's many weird languages around!

Comment: It'll be hard to find a syntax that doesn't clash with *some* programming language. `{}` is used in *so many* languages, for example. Python uses it for sets and dictionaries, including set and dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: Also, messing up *in* the code blocks would make [other usage of the data](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) very hard. (But I know that part of your feature request is just an idea.)

Comment: guys, please don't get hung up on the suggested markdown - it's just a very rough suggestion. We can figure out a better approach if this idea gets support.

Comment: Like I wrote above: I know that the part about "tagging" of the code fragment is just an idea. However, it's probably also the main problem of [feature requests like yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54392): surely the team can come up with some nice rendering (even some that is accessible) once the problem of the tagging has been resolved...

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe link to your [data.se] query/results to provide greater context (I agree it's necessary, but I'd like some idea of the scope of the problem in context of the number of answers posted).

Comment: @DavidThomas OK added link. Actually, it's 853 since new year. Although my criteria is fuzzy, all posts I checked were legitimate cases.