# How to highlight specific lines of code snippet

Tags: feature-request

Taking inspiration from programming books in which different (but similar) blocks of code use bold text to highlight differences between each other, generally new lines or new values, I would like to do it in my answer in SO, but it seems not possibile to combine bolde text with code snippets.

Is there a way to highlight specific lines of code snippet?

In other [similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote) are proposed different solutions, for example putting an "*" in front of new lines, but is a workaround and not what I'm asking.

Thanks

Comment: `You mean you want *it* **bold** like ***this***?` Or do you want markdown to render inside backticks?

Comment: You mean you want *it* **bold** like ***this***?

Comment: ^ the code from @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M

Comment: Yes, but in CODE snippet. for example: how to highlight the word "example" in the following `code example` ?

Comment: See the proposed duplicate.