# Add option to highlight error with special color in code

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

It would be better if programmer can highlight particular error in red or some particular other than bold black one. [Allow highlighting certain bits of a code fragment or quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54392/allow-highlighting-certain-bits-of-a-code-fragment-or-quote) has similar answer but I am not asking the same thing. I am asking for specific code for error.

Comment: So you want red instead of bold. Not good enough imho.

Comment: I mean there should be some specific color specially for error. So that one can directly focused on that one. any ways we can use bold but bold can be useful for focusing other things such as commands etc. Most thing in program code is error .Error must be look separate in each program if any. The use of distinguishing error is expert programmer can look at it around and answer . some times there is no need to look at whole code. Time can be saved in many cases with what I have suggested

Comment: So in this case not a dupe, retracted close vote, but -1 since I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: You all are suggesting is for color a line or word .I am only specifically focused on highlighting error.Highlighting error can save time in many cases . :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is particularly useful. We strive to have the shortest code necessary to reproduce the issue. If you have to highlight a specific line you are most likely having too much code.

I also expect this to get distracting very soon. I think posts will look like its christmas, not like a readable post. You can simply point to a line of code in a comment, like this:

```
int x = 1/0; // <-- error here
```

It is not a state-of-the-art solution, but it works like a charm. It is clear, doesn't distract. A winner to me.

Comment: Thanks Patrick . Appreciate your response