# Preview incorrectly renders non-entities as entities

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

System: Mac OS X, Browser: Firefox 15.0.1 (what other information is needed?).

`&#211hello;` produces Óhello; in the **Preview**.  Similarly with hex: `&#x211bhello;` produces ℛhello;

(They render correctly when posted.)

Comment: What's the problem anyway? What do you expect them to look like?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Sorry, thought that was obvious.  `&#211hello;` should render as `&#211hello;` since it is not a valid entity.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: They are *invalid* entities (`&#xxx;` is the proper format, where xxx is a decimal number).

Comment: What is interesting is that an extra `;` is being implied by the preview. The problem, of course, is that this 'eager fixing' is going to hide your error until you submit your post.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the responsibility falls on the browser, which I believe [shouldn't technically do what it's doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100905/para-turns-into-within-pre/100914#comment256917_100914) by pretending there was a `;` there.

That said, there's no reason that PageDown can't use the same level of strictness in its ampersand encoding that MarkdownSharp does, so updating [`_EncodeAmpsAndAngles`](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Converter.js#1164) to use

```
/&(?!#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*);)/g
```

instead of the more lenient

```
/&(?!#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w+);)/g
```

seems reasonable enough to me.

Comment: I guess the real bug (from SO/SE perspective) is that there is a difference between preview and what eventually gets rendered so I agree that PageDown should use the same encoding whatsit as MarkdownSharp.