# Is there a way to make the text in the code section highlighted?

Tags: support, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bold code in a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question)

I have seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question), which is very old (december 2009).

Are there any updates to it? Is it now possible to mark a line in the code section? (either bold, or different colour, or somehow)

Comment: Nope, nothing new on this topic as far as I know - code block has its own format and colors that you can't change or control apart of telling the language.

Answer (score 0):

The question you link has been tagged as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), which means the feature request will not be implemented. It is possible to highlight a line using the suggestion reported in the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question/32724#32724), and in [the answer given by Brad Gilbert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705/bold-code-in-a-question/32717#32717).